# - jms/payment-core-bundle[dev-master, 1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require doctrine/common ~2.3 -> found doctrine/common[2.3.0-BETA1, ..., 2.13.x-dev]

Tags: symfony, composer-php, bundle, payment

I can not install JMSPaymentCoreBundle here are the errors. How to fix it?

```
Problem 1
    - jms/payment-core-bundle[dev-master, 1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require doctrine/common ~2.3 -> found doctrine/common[2.3.0-BETA1, ..., 2.13.x-dev]
 but the package is fixed to 3.1.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument
 for the update command.
    - jms/payment-core-bundle 1.4.x-dev is an alias of jms/payment-core-bundle dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - Root composer.json requires jms/payment-core-bundle ^1.4 -> satisfiable by jms/payment-core-bundle[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.x-dev (alias of dev-m
aster)].


Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: Please share more details - for example, the package requires v2 of `doctrine/common` while you are already using v3 of that package. What would happen if you downgraded this?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use `jms/payment-core-bundle` for your project? That package has not seen any activity for two years